# Printing contents of all files in a directory C programming

Tags: c

Hello and good evening,

I'm making a program that will gather all the files in a given directory and print out all of the integers inside them.

This is homework but not THE homework.  This is a small part of it that I can't figure out.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mergefiles.c"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if(2 != argc)
{
    printf("Directory name missing!\n");
    return 0;
}
DIR *dp = NULL;
struct dirent *dptr = NULL;
FILE *input_file;
FILE *next_file;
char c;

if (NULL == (dp = opendir(argv[1])))
{
    printf("Cannot open the given directory %s", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    while(NULL != (dptr = readdir(dp)))
    {
        if(!strcmp (dptr->d_name, "."))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(!strcmp (dptr->d_name, ".."))
        {
            continue;
        }

        input_file = fopen(dptr->d_name, "r");
        if(input_file == NULL)
        {
            perror("Cannot open file or no file exists\n");
            fclose(input_file);

            return 0;
        }
        c = fgetc(input_file);
        while(c != EOF)
        {
            printf("%d", c);
        }
        printf(%s\n", dptr->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
return 0;
}
```

I started with this slowly.  First, I read a directory.  Then I printed the names of all the files within the directory.  All of that works just fine (which is really cool!).

However, i'm getting a `segfault` whenever I try to do the `fclose(input_file)` within the first `while loop`.  At first, I thought it was because there was nothing in the file (I fixed this by putting something in the file), but that doesn't work.

Strangely, when I take out the `fclose(input_file)`, it will compile, but throw out the second error: `Cannot open file or file doesn't exist`.

All the files contain integers, one on each line, of varying depth.  I did my best to proofread the code so if there are any errors (typo's and such) let me know and I'll edit it right away.

Thanks for any all words of wisdom. :D

Update:

So I get a `segfault` because the `input_file` is `NULL` and I'm trying to close it...which makes sense and I can't believe I missed it.

What I don't understand is why the `input_file` is `NULL` in the first place.

Comment: You are passing in NULL to fclose.  You need to move that call to the point where you are done reading, not where you tested input_file for NULL.

Comment: Well that solves that mystery, but why would the input_file be NULL in the first place?

Comment: Your code says `if (input_file == NULL)` - clearly, you can't `fclose(input_file)` if `input_file == NULL`; what are you closing? NULL. Input_file would be NULL if opening the file failed. The open can fail for several reasons (opened by another process exclusively, for instance), but why it failed isn't really relevant to your question here. Your code has a flaw where it clearly tries to close something you already know is NULL.

Comment: @KenWhite Ignoring the obvious snarkiness in your comment:

The problem is when I try to open files that I know exist and i've already proven I can read before, I now cannot.  The hours i've spent on this kept me from seeing the obvious flaw in the fclose() that I was doing, but i'm still at a loss for why input_file == null is true in the first place.

Comment: `perror`.......

Comment: There's no *snarkiness*. There *is* the observation that you should actually read the code you're writing. `input_file == null` because `fopen(input_file)` failed. It is never safe to assume that something worked when it might not. I've pointed out one reason why it might fail. Your code correctly checks for failure (`if (input_file == NULL)`), but you didn't think through what you wrote afterward. I pointed out you should read and understand the code you're writing. If you took that as "snarky", my apologies.

Comment: @KenWhite I couldn't agree more.  I should read my my code that i'm writing.  Problem is i've been writing it for...six hours now, so I must have missed it.  

No need to apologize, if you said you didn't write it to be snarky then I believe you. 

However, I don't understand why the input_file is NULL in the first place.  There are files in there to read.

Comment: A second reason (just to get you thinking) that it might fail: There is a lag between the time you access the directory to get the files and the time you try to open it; the file could be moved/renamed/deleted in that interval and the file you think is there isn't any longer. The attribute could change so it's no longer visible. Or (as I said before), it could be locked by another process that opened it in a non-shareable mode. There are many reasons that opening a file can fail.

Comment: @KenWhite do you think that "(dptr = readdir(dp)))" is reading the directory and then returning NULL because it reached the end, before I can actually access the files?

Comment: I'll give you a Windows-centric example. I'm a user sitting at the computer looking at a folder in Explorer. I see a file and think "I don't need that", click on it, and right-click to open the context menu (or start moving my hand to the Delete key). Your app reads the file as being in the folder. I click on (via the menu or keyboard) "Delete", and the file is deleted. Your code tries to open the file that you saw being there half a second ago. Or code elsewhere opens the file exclusively during that quick interval, or it was already open exclusively, which wouldn't prevent listing it.

Comment: A specific case: Open a spreadsheet in Excel. Open Explorer, navigate to the file where that spreadsheet is located, and try to delete it. Even though Explorer can see it's there, you can't delete it because Excel locks it when opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get input_file equal to NULL is obvious, because there is no such file that you want to open is in the current directory.

Suppose for example consider your working directory as (this is where you are compiling your C program)

> /home/student/Myfolder

Let us assume you want to open "Input" folder and there are two files 1.txt and 2.txt.

After compiling what compiler does for **fopen()** is it searches for file as

> /home/student/Myfolder/1.txt

But the actual path is

> /home/student/Myfolder/Input/1.txt

I hope you understand that. To overcome this you have to get the current working directory **cwd()** function and then append the directory name and file name. Below is the complete program. Please do note the commands I have made in the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if(2 != argc)
{
    printf("Directory name missing!\n");
    return 0;
}
DIR *dp = NULL;
struct dirent *dptr = NULL;
FILE *input_file;
FILE *next_file;
char c,cwd[256]; //created new character array

if (NULL == (dp = opendir(argv[1])))
{
    printf("Cannot open the given directory %s", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    while((dptr = readdir(dp))!=NULL)
    {
        if(!strcmp (dptr->d_name, "."))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(!strcmp (dptr->d_name, ".."))
        {
            continue;
        }
    if(getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) //this is important
    {
        printf("No such file or directory");
        continue;
    }
    if(dptr->d_name[0]=='.')  //Files never begin with '.' 
        continue;
    strcat(cwd,"/");   //For windows "\"
    strcat(cwd,argv[1]);
    strcat(cwd,"/");   //For windows "\"
    strcat(cwd,dptr->d_name);
    printf("%s",cwd);  //check for working directory
        input_file = fopen(cwd, "r");
    printf("%s\n",dptr->d_name); //validation check
        if(input_file == NULL)
        {
            perror("Cannot open file or no file exists\n");
            fclose(input_file);
            return 0;
        }
        c = fgetc(input_file);
        while(c != EOF)
        {
            printf("%d", c);
        }
        printf("%s\n", dptr->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
return 0;
}
```